# Assigning [NotMapped] property value after "regular" (mapped) property value has been assigned

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Is there a way to assign a value to a not mapped property after all mapped properties get their values from the DB? For example:

```
public class ProcessSupervisor
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int MaximumConcurrentProcesses { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public int AvailableProcessSlots { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to keep the value of `MaximumConcurrentProcesses` in the database and assign that value to `AvailableProcessSlots` as a default value once Entity Framework instantiates `ProcessSupervisor` DBSet and assigns corresponding values to objects properties. Obviously I cannot assign the value of `MaximumConcurrentProcesses` to `AvailableProcessSlots` in class constructor since `MaximumConcurrentProcesses` hasn't received it's value from database yet. Is there a proper way do do it without initializing the `AvailableProcessSlots` value in some weird and awkward way?

Comment: Sounds like two propeties are doing the same thing. What do you expect `AvailableProcessSlots` setter should do?

Comment: I would like to initialize AvailableProcessSlots with MaximumConcurrentProcesses  value and then decrement AvailableProcessSlots each time slot is being used and increment it back when it's free, but no more that MaximumConcurrentProcesses. Of course that I can rename AvailableProcessSlots to UsedProcessSlots which will be initialized to 0 and then increment and decrement, but I prefer opposite solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
public class ProcessSupervisor
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int MaximumConcurrentProcesses { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    private int? availableProcessSlots = null;
    public int AvailableProcessSlots
    {
        get
        {
            return availableProcessSlots ?? MaximumConcurrentProcesses;
        }
        set
        {
            availableProcessSlots = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: bruno.almeida thanks for the answer, I implemented the same solution, but I was looking for a cleaner way. Anyway, if no one will propose something else, I will mark it as an answer. Thanks!