# Stored Procedure returns value for a column but FromSqlRaw returns null for the class property

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-core

I have a class that is called by multiple methods. This class is:

```
public class Policy : EntityObject
{
    public Guid PolicyId { get; set; }
    public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string PolicyNumber { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string TrimmedPolicyNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime? PolicyEffectiveDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? PolicyExpirationDate { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string PolicyType { get; set; }
    public string InsuranceCompany { get; set; }
    public string WritingCompany { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string BillMethod_PaymentPlan { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public decimal? FullTermPremium { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string AccountExecutive { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string AccountRepresentative { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string PolicyLineOfBusiness { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string Status { get; set; }
```

Now I have the following stored proc:

```
Create PROCEDURE [GetActivePoliciesByCustomer]
@CustomerId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    Select
        c.CustId as CustomerId
        , p.PolId as PolicyId
        , p.PolNo as PolicyNumber
        , p.PolTypeLOB as [PolicyLineOfBusiness]
        , p.PolEffDate as PolicyEffectiveDate
        , p.PolExpDate as PolicyExpirationDate
        , cmp.Name as InsuranceCompany
        , wcmp.Name as WritingCompany
        , pr.Description as [Status]
    FROM
        Policies p
        (Further details have been omitted as it is not important)
GO
```

This stored proc returns data for all the fields listed above. However, when I make the following call:

```
public async Task<List<Policy>> GetActivePoliciesByCustomerId(Guide customerId)
{
    var activePolicies = await _context.Policy
        .FromSqlRaw<Policy>("EXEC [GetActivePoliciesByCustomer] @customerId={0}", customerId)
        .ToListAsync();

    return activepolicies;
}
```

During the debug session, I see that Status and PolicyLineOfBusiness are set to null. My suspicion is that the `[NotMapped]` attribute is preventing these fields from getting mapped and I have validated that. If I remove `[NotMapped]` attribute, I see that the Status and PolicyLineOfBusiness fields are populated. However, this class (Policy) is used by another call:

```
public async Task<Policy> GetPolicyByPolicyId(Guid id)
{
    var policyDetails = await _context.Policy
        .FromSqlRaw<Policy>("EXEC [GetPolicyDetailsByPolicyId] @policyId={0}", id)
        .ToListAsync();

    return policyDetails.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

The stored proc it is calling:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [GetPolicyDetailsByPolicyId]
@PolicyId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT TOP 1
        p.PolId as PolicyId
        , p.CustId as CustomerId
        , p.PolNo as PolicyNumber
        , p.ShortPolNo as TrimmedPolicyNumber
        , p.PolEffDate as PolicyEffectiveDate
        , p.PolExpDate as PolicyExpirationDate
        , p.PolTypeLOB as PolicyType
        , c.[Name] as InsuranceCompany
        , wc.[Name] as WritingCompany
        , p.BillMethod_PaymentPlan
        , p.FullTermPremium
        , e1.[LastName] as AccountExecutive
        , CONCAT(e.FirstName, ' ', e.LastName) as AccountRepresentative 
    From
        Policies p
        (Further details have been omitted as it is not important)
```

If I remove the `[NotMapped]` attribute from the aforementioned properties (PolicyLineOfBusiness and Status) and use the previous method (GetPolicyByPolicyId) to call the above stored proc, I get an exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The required column 'PolicyLineOfBusiness' was not present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation.
```

So how do I solve the problem of making attributes optional and at the same time, they should be able to map to the fields returned by two different stored procs? If there's a better way, I am open to suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this about what is answered here: [Assigning NotMapped property value after "regular" (mapped) property value has been assigned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52953340/assigning-notmapped-property-value-after-regular-mapped-property-value-has) ?

Comment: Maybe you can have a class with common fields, and create another class with inheritance for the second stored procedure? Or is it not an option?

Comment: unrelated but why would a proc called 'GetPolicyDetailsByPolicyId' require a TOP 1 ?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above SQL is product specific.)

Comment: Please make the [sample code](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) minimal and complete. Most of the `Policy` properties & DB columns could be removed, and a declaration for `_context` added.

Comment: Which version of C# is used? Are [nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/nullable-reference-types) enabled? By default, all [reference types should be optional](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-properties?tabs=data-annotations%2Cwithout-nrt#required-and-optional-properties).

Comment: I don't really understand your question; you appear to be asking "how can I have a property that I do not decorate with NotMapped, but won't cause EF to complain 'the property X isn't present in the data' when I don't select it in the data" -> EF's complaint is entirely reasonable; you've told it "I want you to get the PolicyWhatever property data" and then you haven't provided it, so it is complaining - what would you like it to do instead?

Comment: var policyDetails = await _context.Policy
        .FromSqlRaw("EXECUTE  ?IfYouHaveSchema-Or-dbo?.GetPolicyDetailsByPolicyId {0}", id)
        .ToListAsync();

Change between ? as dbo or your schema name for procedures. then Can you try this.

Answer (score 1):

This solution could help you out.

First, we need to use inheritance.

Second, we have to create a discriminator to handle the SPs and classes.

Finally, we set the discriminator in the stored procedures.

Let's see some code.

1. Using your class:

```
public class Policy : EntityObject
{
    public Guid PolicyId { get; set; }
    public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string PolicyNumber { get; set; }    
    public DateTime? PolicyEffectiveDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? PolicyExpirationDate { get; set; }
    public string InsuranceCompany { get; set; }
    public string WritingCompany { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerPolicy : Policy
{
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string PolicyLineOfBusiness { get; set; }        
}

public class DetailedPolicy : Policy
{    
    public string TrimmedPolicyNumber { get; set; }
    public string PolicyType { get; set; }
    public string BillMethod_PaymentPlan { get; set; }    
    public decimal? FullTermPremium { get; set; }    
    public string AccountExecutive { get; set; }
    public string AccountRepresentative { get; set; }
}
```

2. Setting the discriminator:

```
public class Policy : EntityObject
{
    public Guid PolicyId { get; set; }
    // ...
    [NotMapped]  
    public string discriminator { get; set; } 
}
```

Then, fluent API settings

```
// ...
public DbSet<Policy> Policy { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  // here you can use enum, byte, int, etc. instead of string.
  modelBuilder.Entity<Policy>()
    .HasDiscriminator<string>("discriminator")
    .HasValue<Policy>(nameof(Policy)) 
    .HasValue<CustomerPolicy>(nameof(CustomerPolicy))
    .HasValue<DetailedPolicy>(nameof(DetailedPolicy));
  // ...
}
```

3. In this step we have to pass the discriminator (class name) to the stored procedures.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [GetPolicyDetailsByPolicyId]
@PolicyId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT TOP 1
        p.PolId as PolicyId
        , p.CustId as CustomerId
        , p.PolNo as PolicyNumber
        , p.ShortPolNo as TrimmedPolicyNumber
        , p.PolEffDate as PolicyEffectiveDate
        , p.PolExpDate as PolicyExpirationDate
        , p.PolTypeLOB as PolicyType
        , c.[Name] as InsuranceCompany
        , wc.[Name] as WritingCompany
        , p.BillMethod_PaymentPlan
        , p.FullTermPremium
        , e1.[LastName] as AccountExecutive
        , CONCAT(e.FirstName, ' ', e.LastName) as AccountRepresentative 

        // Add the discriminator here
        ,'DetailedPolicy' discriminator

    From
        Policies p
        (Further details have been omitted as it is not important)
```

Repeat in the other sp.

```
Create PROCEDURE [GetActivePoliciesByCustomer]
@CustomerId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    Select
        c.CustId as CustomerId
        , p.PolId as PolicyId
        , p.PolNo as PolicyNumber
        , p.PolTypeLOB as [PolicyLineOfBusiness]
        , p.PolEffDate as PolicyEffectiveDate
        , p.PolExpDate as PolicyExpirationDate
        , cmp.Name as InsuranceCompany
        , wcmp.Name as WritingCompany
        , pr.Description as [Status]

        // Add the discriminator here
        'CustomerPolicy' discriminator
         
    FROM
        Policies p
        (Further details have been omitted as it is not important)
GO
```

EF Context calls:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;

// ...

var activePolicies = await context.Policy
    .FromSqlRaw("exec [GetActivePoliciesByCustomer] @customerId", 
        new SqlParameter("customerId", customerId))
    .AsAsyncEnumerable();

var policyDetails = await context.Policy
    .FromSqlRaw("exec [GetPolicyDetailsByPolicyId] @policyId", 
        new SqlParameter("policyId", id))
    .AsAsyncEnumerable();
```

Note: you may need to use AsAsyncEnumerable or IQueryable to cast your class correctly.

**Update:**

Note2: if the compiler shows problems, you have to fill all fields with null from the other derived class.

For instance:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [GetPolicyDetailsByPolicyId]
// ...
        ,'DetailedPolicy' discriminator
        ,null Status
        ,null PolicyLineOfBusiness 
// ...
```

Here's an example with .NET Core 5 and EF Core 5:

```
public class Policy
{
  public int field1 { get; set; }    
  [NotMapped]
  public string discriminator { get; set; } 
}

public class Policy2 : Policy
{
  public int? field2 { get; set; }
}

public class Policy3 : Policy
{
  public int? field3 { get; set; }
}
```

Fluent API:

```
// ...
public DbSet<Policy> Policies { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  modelBuilder.Entity<Policy>().HasNoKey();
  
  modelBuilder.Entity<Policy>()
    .HasDiscriminator<string>("discriminator")
    .HasValue<Policy>(nameof(Policy))
    .HasValue<Policy2>(nameof(Policy2))
    .HasValue<Policy3>(nameof(Policy3));

  //...
}
```

Custom stored procedure:

```
create procedure GenPolicyQuery
    @id int,
    @source varchar(10)
as

declare @field1 int, @field2 int, @field3 int

if @source =  'Policy'
    set @field1 = @id
else if @source = 'Policy2'
    select @field1 = 10, @field2 = @id
else if @source = 'Policy3'
    select @field1 = 10, @field3 = @id

select @field1 field1, @field2 field2, @field3 field3, @source discriminator

go
```

Results:

```
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
// ...

var policy1 = db.Policies
  .FromSqlRaw("exec GenPolicyQuery @id, @source", 
    new SqlParameter("id", 10), 
    new SqlParameter("source", "Policy"))        
  .AsEnumerable();

var policy2 = db.Policies
  .FromSqlRaw("exec GenPolicyQuery @id, @source", 
    new SqlParameter("id", 20), 
    new SqlParameter("source", "Policy2"))
  .AsEnumerable();

var policy3 = db.Policies
  .FromSqlRaw("exec GenPolicyQuery @id, @source", 
    new SqlParameter("id", 30), 
    new SqlParameter("source", "Policy3"))
  .AsEnumerable();
    
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(policy1));
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(policy2));
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(policy3))

// Result
/*
  [{"field1":10,"discriminator":"Policy"}]
  [{"field2":20,"field1":10,"discriminator":"Policy2"}]
  [{"field3":30,"field1":10,"discriminator":"Policy3"}]
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

For the separate stored procedure you will need to have separate models as the column are different in both the stored procedures.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Policies` class you have both `PolicyType` and `PolicyLineOfBusiness` properties.

in `GetActivePoliciesByCustomer` procedure the column `p.PolTypeLOB` is aliased as `PolicyLineOfBusiness` but in `GetPolicyDetailsByPolicyId` procedure the column `p.PolTypeLOB` is aliased as `PolicyType`

So, the origin column is the same for both properties, I'm not understanding the reason,
but to avoid the exception on 2nd procedure you can modify it adding also the required output for `PolicyLineOfBusiness` :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [GetPolicyDetailsByPolicyId]
@PolicyId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT TOP 1
        p.PolId as PolicyId
        , p.CustId as CustomerId
        , p.PolNo as PolicyNumber
        , p.ShortPolNo as TrimmedPolicyNumber
        , p.PolEffDate as PolicyEffectiveDate
        , p.PolExpDate as PolicyExpirationDate
        , p.PolTypeLOB as PolicyType
        , p.PolTypeLOB as PolicyLineOfBusiness /* *** ADD THIS LINE  *** */
        , c.[Name] as InsuranceCompany
        , wc.[Name] as WritingCompany
        , p.BillMethod_PaymentPlan
        , p.FullTermPremium
        , e1.[LastName] as AccountExecutive
        , CONCAT(e.FirstName, ' ', e.LastName) as AccountRepresentative 
    From
        Policies p
        (Further details have been omitted as it is not important)
```

Answer (score 0):

As **PolicyLineOfBusiness** property is present at your domain model. So the both SP must return that property value if you remove the attribute(NotMapped). But by removing that attribute your second SP will give an exception and the first SP will get data. So it means that the second SP does not want to return **PolicyLineOfBusiness** property.

Unfortunately, you can not do that as you write **PolicyLineOfBusiness** property mandatory by removing the attribute(NotMapped) at the domain Model property. So you have to return the property from the second SP if you want to keep the domain model the same.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [GetPolicyDetailsByPolicyId]
@PolicyId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT TOP 1
        p.PolId as PolicyId
        , p.CustId as CustomerId
        , p.PolNo as PolicyNumber
        , p.ShortPolNo as TrimmedPolicyNumber
        , p.PolEffDate as PolicyEffectiveDate
        , p.PolExpDate as PolicyExpirationDate
        , p.PolTypeLOB as PolicyType
        , c.[Name] as InsuranceCompany
        , wc.[Name] as WritingCompany
        , p.BillMethod_PaymentPlan
        , p.FullTermPremium
        , "" As PolicyLineOfBusiness --Have to add this as the domain model contain this property
        , e1.[LastName] as AccountExecutive
        , CONCAT(e.FirstName, ' ', e.LastName) as AccountRepresentative 
    From
        Policies p
        (Further details have been omitted as it is not important)
```

If you do not want to do this then create 2 different models for 2 SPs.